# Weight paint on an armature seems to change randomly when I revisit bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, mirror

**When I paint the bones on the arm for example, everything looks fine initially. Coming back to the bone later, I find that the bone suddenly has influence on points on the torso.**

I'm trying to rig a humanoid model and I'm currently on the weight painting step.

I created an armature and parented the mesh to the armature with automatic weights.

This step gave pretty crazy (weight painting related) results so I started to manually weight paint. Based on the suggestion from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fICQmBEt4Y, I enabled auto-normalize and x-mirror for the tool. I unchecked front faces only and changed fall off to projected.

Some other info about the mesh - I have a mirror modifier on - I don't think it's the cause of the problem but I'm not sure. The mesh also has a 'displacement' modifier from Retopoflow and a Subdivision modifier.

So the order of modifiers is:

- mirror
- displacement
- subdivision
- armature

Is there anything that I might be doing wrong here? When I paint the bones on the arm for example, everything looks fine initially. Coming back to the bone later, I find that the bone suddenly has influence on points on the torso.